# Put javascript directly in views instead of assets/javascript in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When we generate a model, such as Fruit, it auto generates `assets/javascripts/fruits.js`

However, say if we have javascript callbacks for only a paragraph element in `views/fruits/show.html`, should it be placed directly in `show.html`? Is it more conventional or faster to put it in `fruits.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [content_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for) to achieve it.

```
<%# views/layouts/application.html.erb %>
<head>
  <title>My Website</title>
  <%= yield :script %>
</head>

<%# views/fruits/show.html %>
<% content_for :script do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :fruits %>
<% end %>
```